# How to assign the values for an HttpRequestMessage class?

Tags: rest, f#, dotnet-httpclient

I struggle with assigning values to an 'HttpRequestMessage' class.
My code is:

```
let requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage()
requestMsg.RequestUri = new System.Uri("https://yh-finance.p.rapidapi.com/stock/v2/get-summary?symbol=BMW.DE&region=DE");;
```

When I assign the URL, I get the response:

```
val it : bool = false
```

I tried to assign a different Method but also got the same response.

```
> requestMsg.Method = HttpMethod.Post;;
val it : bool = false
```

`requestMsg` has this content:

```
> requestMsg;;
val it : HttpRequestMessage =
  Method: GET, RequestUri: '<null>', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
}
    {Content = null;
     Headers = seq [];
     Method = GET;
     Options = seq [];
     Properties = seq [];
     RequestUri = null;
     Version = 1.1;
     VersionPolicy = RequestVersionOrLower;}
```

How can I modify the `HttpRequestMessage` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment in F# is done with `<-`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/values/#mutable-variables

```
requestMsg.Method <- HttpMethod.Post
```